# Can a WCF hosted in windows service impersonate a domain windows caller from asp.net web application?

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have a web application that has reference of the wcf service which is deployed on a windows service.  Web user sends a request to WCF service which then calls a stored procedure.
Web application is running under Windows Authentication and Impersonate ticked.
WCF is running as wshttp binding.

This is all located on same machine.  I want the WCF service to impersonate the web application user.  Is this possible? Can someone please guide me how to achieve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible. There are some minor limitations if the application and service are running on the same system, but your scenario should not suffer from that. 
From [How to: Impersonate a Client on a Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731090.aspx):

> When the client and service are running on the same computer and the
>   client is running under a system account (that is, Local System or
>   Network Service), the client cannot be impersonated when a secure
>   session is established with stateful Security Context tokens. A
>   WinForms or console application typically is run under the currently
>   logged in account, so that account can be impersonated by default.
>   However, when the client is an ASP.NET page and that page is hosted in
>   IIS 6.0 or IIS 7.0, then the client does run under the Network Service
>   account by default. All of the system-provided bindings that support
>   secure sessions use a stateless Security Context token by default.
>   However, if the client is an ASP.NET page and secure sessions with
>   stateful Security Context tokens are used, the client cannot be
>   impersonated.

There are not specific limitations if your service is running as a windows service.

Comment: what are the minor limitations?

Comment: Improved the answer to include the limitations.